Prove that Tarski's axiom implies the existence of inaccessibile cardinals.
Tarski's axiom states that for every set $s$ there exists a set $u$ such that:

$s\in u$;
$(\forall x)\Biggl((x\in u)\to\biggl((\forall y)\Bigl((y\subseteq x)\to(y\in u)\Bigr)\biggr)\Biggr)$;
$(\forall x)\Bigl((x\in u)\to(\mathscr P(x)\in u)\Bigr)$;
$(\forall x)\biggl((x\subseteq u)\to\Bigl((|x|<|u|)\to(x\in u)\Bigr)\biggr)$.

I know (see here) that Tarski's axiom implies existence of inaccessibile cardinals but I do not found anywhere the formal proof so that I thought to put here a specific question: could someone help me, please?

I'm not an expert, but aren't the 2nd and 3rd bullet points saying the same thing?

Oh, never mind, I see the difference. The 3rd bullet point says the the collection of all subsets of $x$ is in $u$, while the first says that each subset of $x$ is in $u$.
